# ASP .NET Identity разные типы пользователей. Как спроектировать БД?

Tags: база-данных, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Мне нужно реализовать несколько пользователей с разными ролями: администратор, обычный пользователь и т.д., при этом у администратора, например, могут быть дополнительные поля, которых нет у пользователя. 
Я только начала изучать ASP .NET MVC, а время очень ограничено (пишу диплом), поэтому хотелось бы получить совет, как это реализовать проще всего (и как делается обычно). Использую Code First.
Подойдет ли такой вариант: 
Имеется таблица AspNetUsers с общими полями, с которой связаны связью 1 - 0..1 таблицы AdminInfo и UserInfo, в которых имеются дополнительные поля. Считается ли нормальной такая структура БД?
Сначала пробовала сделать иерархию классов (AdminInfo и UserInfo наследники ApplicationUser) и испольовать подход TPT (table per type), но запуталась при регистрации, ведь в Identity уже есть механизм создания пользователя. Сама понимаю, что слабо разобралась в теме, но буду признательна, если укажете, в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: а какие доп. поля могут быть у админа и прочих ролей? для чего это?

Comment: Проще всего просто оставлять админские доп. поля у обычных пользователей пустыми.

Comment: Например, у пользователя есть такие поля как возраст, пол, интересы и т.п. Так как администратор в принципе не является такого типа пользователем, то у него не должно быть этих данных. Администратор только управляет другими пользователями. И допустим, есть 3й тип пользователя (1-й был ученик, 2-й администратор, 3-й - учитель). Понятно, что у учителя не будет полей "класс", "средний балл". Если это допустимо - оставлять столько полей пустыми и не противоречит никаким нормам проектирования  БД, то действительно, наверное,это самое простое в моем случае решение.